# Is this Oath of Bees Paladin subclass balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew-review, paladin

Mostly I am looking to see if the damage output Channel Divinity, and Aura are on par with other paladin oaths, and dont break the game.

### *Oath of Bees*

#### Tenets of the Bees

The tenets of the Oath of Bees are often set by following the way of the bee, and generally emphasize the following tenets.

**Friends.** Friends are more important than anything, a person without friends is not a person, but mere dust.

**Mind.** Strength of the mind is strength of the body, a bee can control itself, emotions come second.

**Perseverance**. Nothing stops the bee from its goal. No matter the cost, no matter the risk, once a bee decides to do something, nothing is more important.

### Oath Spells

| Spell level | Spell name |
| --- | --- |
| 3rd | Feather Fall, Speak with Animals |
| 5th | Flock of Familiars |
| 9th | Conjure Animals |
| 13th | Giant Insect |
| 17th | Insect Plague |

#### Channel Divinity

When you take this oath at 3rd level, you gain the following Channel Divinity options.

- **Hum and Sting.** As a bonus action, you can use your Channel Divinity to begin the hum of the bee. For the next minute, you can add your Charisma modifier to attack and damage rolls. If you score a critical hit during the duration, you can add 1d4 acid damage to the total damage.
- **Bee Flight.** As a bonus action, you can use your Channel Divinity to activate your bee flight. For the next 5 rounds, you have a 10ft fly speed, and all of your attacks do an extra 1d8 acid damage.

#### Aura of Bees

Beginning at 7th level, Bees fly around you so heavily upon you that it forms an wall of sight. You and friendly creatures within 5ft of you cannot be seen, as if you are heavily obscured. You and friendly creatures can see out, but other creatures only see the bees swarming. You can turn this on and off as a bonus action.

At 18th level, the range of this aura increases to 10ft.

#### Eye of the Swarm

Starting at 15th level, your swarm shall contain an enemy for you. Once per long rest, you can cause a swarm to engulf a medium or smaller creature. That creature cannot see anything beyond 10 ft for 6 rounds. They can only see past the bees using truesight. Any creature that comes within 10 ft of them has the same effect on their own sight. If they move, the bees follow the creature that this effect was used on.

#### Infinibee

At 20th level, the powers of the bee become one with you, and you gain the following abilities.

- A permanent 10ft magical fly speed.
- Your unarmed strikes deal 2d8 magical piercing damage, and you can smite with them.
- Whenever you fall below 15 HP, bees surround you, giving you a +1 to AC and all rolls.

Comment: When you have a moment we have a couple posts with some guidance for getting the most out of homebrew review questions. There are some details you can add to your post that would really help us get a better idea of what sort of help you are looking for. See these discussions for details: [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121), [How should I ask about my D&D 5e Homebrew being balanced?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8171)

Comment: Balance is one thing, but I don't see how this fits the oath idea. It's bee affinity, but how is it an oath? Also, please link to v1, to make it easier for people to see what's changed and what was previous concerns.

Comment: @Mołot I triple checked the V1 myself, and it was broken, so I just re-did it.

Comment: @matszwecja [Please do not write answers in comments.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments).

Comment: This is your v1 here, and you should do a lot more than one self review before posting here.

Comment: Access to spell level 17 is clearly broken :)

Comment: All of the barmaids call  him "honey" ...

Comment: Later, that VERY SAME BEE!

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin someone edited it, i didnt put it there like that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Biggest Issue - Aura

As it is, the 7th level aura feature is absolutely completely broken. It gives permanent benefit of 4th level spell (Shadow of Moil) to you and everyone around you. It's permanent advantage on attack rolls you make and disadvantage on attack made on you for everything that does not have blindsight, not to mention disabling all sight-based spells etc.
This alone makes the subclass instant reject.

### Feature overlap

15th level feature may cause your enemy to be effectively blinded beyond 10ft radius. All fun and games except **he already can't see you** due to aura. It could also use some save against effect cause you know, disabling bosses without any chance to give them a response is kinda broken.

Other features also have a lot of overlap - there is no good reason for both CD to give bonus damage (also, compare first option with Oath of Devotion Sacred Weapon - do you have a valid reason for your CD doing same thing PLUS additional damage? Comparing power level to existing features is a great start to making sure your features stay balanced.)

Overlap #3 - 20th level feature gives flight, making 2nd CD option redundant.

### Minor nitpicks

While not a balance issue, 5e commonly uses a single round or x minutes duration. Seeing 5 and 6 round effect duration just feels... weird.
"all rolls" should really be replaced with something more precise, e.g. "attack rolls, ability checks and saving throws". Just in case.

Comment: Thank you for the response, i shall make changes.